# Setting height of TableRow

Tags: android, tablerow

I have two types of content for TableRow. One has two lines and the other one. I wish everyone had the same height. I'm trying something like this:

`tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 80));`

Any other ideas? And, how can I transform "80" in dp?

Comment: [Here's another SO question about setting values in DP programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units)

Comment: This post solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android and setting width and height programmatically in dp units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units)

Answer (score 1):

you can set the hight by setting the padding

```
    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        >
```

for dynamic

tr.setPadding(0, 12, 0, 12);

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different layouts for the rows and just assign them dynamically in your code.   Define the heights in your layouts.

Comment: I wanna do that programmatically

Comment: OK then.  The 2nd parameter is the height.  So what you need to do is make that wrap_content.  Like this:  TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear... but I dont wanna Wrap.. I wish define a number to my height, like I said on my ask.

Answer (score -1):

I Solve this with getViewTreeObserver. You must type this method on the `tableLayout` AND override `onGlobalLayout`.

Inside this method, you can verify all child's height. Then you can identify Max heigh.