# How to set the width of a button in dp during runtime in android?

Tags: android, button

I have an android application. There are a lot of buttons in it but these buttons are created during runtime. If i set the width `button.setwidth(300)` it will set the width to 300px. I want the width to be set in dp. Is there any way around?

Comment: Use This        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units

Comment: Have a look at [this][1]. I think that's what you'll be wanting.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no setWidth(300dp). The workaround is to get the display size, and adjust the 300px variable accordingly.

I must say that there's probably a better way to create a nice layout. Have you tried using nested linearlayouts and layout_weights?

Answer (score 12):

You have to use `TypedValue.applyDimension` to get the pixel count of dp's. Here's an example:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpInPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DP, 300, dm);
```

That will give the the pixel value of 300dp programmatically.

Cheers

Comment: its COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP , a small typo.

Answer (score 2):

Android doen't have separate method for setting button's dimensions in dp. You have to:

```
//Find screen density scale factor
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
myButton.setWidth((int)(100 * scale));
myButton.setHeight((int)(50 * scale));
```