# Unit in Changing RelativeLayout Programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I tried to change RelativeLayout's height programmatically, that is using Java. I have the following code:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.center);
rl.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

I'm bothered of the unit of height.

Is it `px`, `dp` or some other unit?

If it is `px`, is there a way I can use `dp` since `dp` is more advisable than `px` because it's actually dynamic?

Comment: Convert dps to pixels [you can find answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units/5255256#5255256