# How can we set height and width dp for imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I would like to set height and width in `dp` for `ImageView` in android pragmatically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units ,http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/use-dip-sp-metrics-programmatically/try this

Comment: you accept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23575369/5993410) as an answer!

Answer (score 73):

Set width & height with dp :

```
imageview.getLayoutParams().height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageview_height);
imageview.getLayoutParams().width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageview_width);
```

In your dimens.xml provide values for the keys :

```
<dimen name="imageview_width">50dp</dimen> 
<dimen name="imageview_height">50dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Thanks Andros,but I am getting incompatible type error while trying to implement this how can resolve it or am i missing something here..

Comment: great answer dude.

Answer (score 30):

Use display metrics to get the sale factor and then just some simple maths - example, if I want 200x150dp:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpWidthInPx  = (int) (200 * scale);
int dpHeightInPx = (int) (150 * scale);
```

Then set the image view size:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpWidthInPx, dpHeightInPx);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be simpler and should do the trick:

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
LayoutParams params = im.getLayoutParams();
params.height = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_height);
params.width = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_width);
```

And in your dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="item_height">80dp</dimen> 
<dimen name="item_width">80dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Why do you say "simpler"?  I don't see any neatness or simplicity in this...

Answer (score 1):

This may help you...

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
LayoutParams params = im.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
```

Comment: DisplayMetrics metrics = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
int px = (int) (dp * logicalDensity + 0.5);   this may help u in converting pixels to dp

Comment: Lalith does the 0.5 stays a common factor for all devices or it will be different..

Comment: please select this answer as correct, if it satisfies ur question

Answer (score 1):

1. at first choose a desirable dip and assign it to a var.

> int dipAmount=350;

2. Then read the height of your ImageView.

> `float scale = imageview.Resource.DisplayMetrics.Density;`

3. Convert from px to dip.

> `int converter =(int) (350 * scale + 0.5f);`

4. Set the height to imageview.

> `imageView.LayoutParameters.Height=converter;`

Answer (score 1):

```
 final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int height_ = (int) (250 * scale + 0.5f);
int width_ = (int) (250 * scale + 0.5f);
```

250 is in dp

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ImageView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height_;
params.width = width_;

ImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
image_view.getLayoutParams().width= 20;
```

Give me your feedback if it's acceptable. It's work for me.