# Creating multiple views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to inflate a view multiple times.
my view consists of one imageview and a textview below it and placing it at particular position.

Below is my **item.xml** which I am inflating multiple times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code with inflate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    final View v = linf.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    TextView tvs = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView ivs = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tvs.setText(i+"");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

    int w = (mWidth/2)-50;
    int h =(mHeight/2)-50;
    params.leftMargin = w;
    params.topMargin = h;
    Log.e("W-H", mWidth + "-" + mHeight);
    rr.addView(v,params);
}
```

I am able to place the **item.xml** successfully but its not fitting screen properly I have set height and width fixed 100dp.

Here is what I am getting
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MznxX.png)

Comment: `I have set height and width fixed 100dp.` Not really. This `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);` is **pixels**, not **dp**s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for `LayoutParams` is in pixels, so you have to convert to dps for it to display correctly on your screen. This can be accomplished as in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255256/6543020):

```
int width_dps = 100;
int height_dps = 100;
final float scale = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width_pixels = (int) (width_dps * scale + 0.5f);
int height_pixels = (int) (height_dps * scale + 0.5f);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width_pixels, height_pixels);
```

Alternatively, if you are using a fixed size, you can update your xml to allow `wrap_content` to work correctly. You will be overriding the `LinearLayout` params, so you can update your subviews:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and update a subview (`android:layout_width="100dp"`):

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```