# how to change stroke color in android by kotlin code?

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to change border color for imageview manually in kotlin.

```
val backgroundGradient = imgIcon.getBackground() as GradientDrawable
backgroundGradient.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow))
```

i tried this but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this method

```
backgroundGradient.setStroke(width : Int, color : Int)
```

there are other options available you can pass to method

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setStroke` method to change border color of imageview.

```
backgroundGradient.setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(context, someColorId))
```

Comment: how can i set width in dp?

Comment: either calculate width or use TypedValue ........ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units