# Is there any way to get the actual height of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have layout which includes some button, textviews and a recyclerview.

The layout already has a scrollView, so i disabled `scroll` of `recyclerView`.

Now i want to set the height of recyclerView programatically.

This is what i am doing right now.

```
    int totalItems= cardsRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=rvCards.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=200*totalItems;
    rvCards.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here i am hardcoding `200` for testing, and its working fine, but i am using `wrap_content` for image height, and image height can be of any length, so i want to calculate the height the right way.

Is there any way to get the actual height of recycler view?

Comment: Convert it to pixel : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units

Comment: @AslamHossin : Thanks, but i need to know how to get the actual height of recyclerAdapter, without hard coding any number.

Comment: Create e custom RecyclerView and override the onMeasure Method . Check my answer below.